# How to get current date and time in ISO 8601 format in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, iso8601, current-time

I am trying to get the current date and time in ISO 8601 format. My code below returns the date 14 days later and incorrect time. I need the correct format and current date for an api request.

```
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").apply {
        this.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST")
    }

val now = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"))

val sendDateUAT = formatter.format(now.time)
Log.d(TAG, "sendDate: $sendDateUAT")
```

This returns: `2019-08-05T02:53:40Z`

**EDIT:** This is now.time:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1564973620006,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=GMT,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=32,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_YEAR=217,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=2,HOUR_OF_DAY=2,MINUTE=53,SECOND=40,MILLISECOND=6,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this locally. Where are you executing this code? I suspect the clock is incorrect.

Comment: Can you verify the result of `now.time` is expected? i.e. just format it with standard UTC formatting to see what the result is and compare to your machines current time. Your format looks correct for extracting 6801; at least from several examples I've seen online.

Comment: @HoratiusCocles I just updated my question with `now.time` result.

Comment: @Phil I am executing this code within android studio. It should be getting the computer system time, which is set to CST.

Comment: And just to clarify, your machine clock does not match the return of that method correct?

Comment: @HoratiusCocles Yes I just checked my emulator and it is set to current date and correct timezone.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: 1564973620006 is GMT: Monday 5. August 2019 02:53:40.006. Looks to me like the time of day is right for when you asked your question, but the date is 2 weeks ahead. Also `MONTH=7` means August (argh!) and you’ve got `DAY_OF_MONTH=5`.

Comment: I found the solution not sure how its much different from the code above but it works lol. I appreciate all of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a helper class that you can use to convert your dates:

```
public object DateHelper {
    private const val ISO_8601_24H_FULL_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

    @JvmName("toIsoStringNullable")
    fun Date?.toIsoString(): String? {
        return this?.toIsoString()
    }

    fun Date.toIsoString(): String {
        val dateFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(ISO_8601_24H_FULL_FORMAT)
        return dateFormat.format(this)
    }
}
```

It can be used very concisely like this:

```
Date().toIsoString()
```

Answer (score -1):

For some reason this fixed the problem and returned the correct date.

```
val today = Calendar.getInstance()
val sendDateUAT = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").format(today.time)
```

Comment: Thaks for answering your own question. The answer is not correct, though. `Z` is an offset (of 0 from UTC), so appending it to a date and time that may have (usually has) a different offset gives an incorrect result.